# how to check String is valid hex color code in android

Tags: java, android

I had a String  which I need to validate whether it is valid hex color code or not .
My sample strings are as follows :

> 1 - #ff00000
>
> 2 -#ff347820

How to validate the above strings to check whether they are valid hex color codes or not .

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-hex-color-code-with-regular-expression/

Comment: This is only a simple regular expression #, followed by 3 or 6 or 8 hex numbers (a-f0-9)

Comment: that would be 3, 6, 8 or **4** numbers

Answer (score 19):

The proper Android way of testing this, independently of supporting future formats, is to rely on the [`Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) class.

Like this:

```
try {
    Color color = Color.parseColor(myColorString);
    // color is a valid color
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    // This color string is not valid
}
```

As a bonus, it also supports named colors such as `magenta`, `blue`...

The main pro over regex matching is semantic. This code explicitly tests the `myColorString` String against being a Color. You practically don't need any comment at all to tell what is does.

Comment: How do i use this in my java application, can u give link to the java library

Answer (score 17):

You can use a regular expression to do so, in which case the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class is what you need:

```
Pattern colorPattern = Pattern.compile("#([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{8})");
Matcher m = colorPattern.matcher(yourInputString);
boolean isColor = m.matches();
```

Comment: @neoexpert No, it won't. Only 3, 6 or 8 hex characters after the "#" are accepted by this pattern.

Comment: I just checked it. You need an "\\b" at the end of your pattern

Comment: Did you run the above code? Note the `matches()` call, which ensures the entire input string matches the pattern. This makes the use of `^`, `$`, or `\b` unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I used m.find(). But with "\\b" at the end m.find() works for me. I need it to highlight all the color values in a html code with corresponding color

Comment: Indeed, using `find()` requires a bit of plumbing for how you find matches in a text. But that was not the OP's question, hence the simpler pattern for the use case at hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186383/discussion-between-neoexpert-and-joffrey).

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.javacodegeeks.java.core;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HexColorValidator {

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String HEX_PATTERN = "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$";

public HexColorValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN);
}

public boolean validate(final String hexColorCode) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(hexColorCode);
    return matcher.matches();

}
}
```

Code from http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/matcher/how-to-validate-hex-color-code-with-regular-expression/